# Synchronous Web Api and response time depending on the thread and request count

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, synchronous

I'm messing with sync/async to learn them better and encountered one thing that I can't explain. I've set up Web Api project with two endpoints which read data from the db. One is sync another one is async. Both do the same operation that takes ~5s on the database side (intentionally throttled). Also I throttled web server in terms of threads:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2, 2);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(2, 2);
```

Currenyly I'm worried by synchronous method behaviour, async works as I expect it to work.

When I send 3 requests to **synchronous** endpoint simultaneously, I end up with 2 responses in 5 seconds, and 1 response in 10 seconds, which seems logical to me:

[image]

However, when I send 4 requests to **synchronous** endpoint simultaneously, I end up with 4 responses which all take 10 seconds (but I expect 2 to be 5s and other 2 to be 10s)

[image]

In web server logs i see that these 4 requests in fact processed synchronously and response times are ~5s:

> ```js
>  
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:57128/test/syncDb  
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:57128/test/syncDb  
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
>       Executing endpoint 'WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait)'
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
>       Executing endpoint 'WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait)'
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
>       Route matched with {action = "GetSyncDb", controller = "Test"}. Executing controller action with signature System.String GetSyncDb() on controller WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController (WebApiAsyncAwait).
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
>       Route matched with {action = "GetSyncDb", controller = "Test"}. Executing controller action with signature System.String GetSyncDb() on controller WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController (WebApiAsyncAwait).
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
>       Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
>       Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>       Executed action WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait) in 5008.3885ms
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>       Executed action WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait) in 5010.472000000001ms
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
>       Executed endpoint 'WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait)'
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
>       Request finished in 5026.9979ms 200 text/plain; charset=utf-8
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
>       Executed endpoint 'WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait)'
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
>       Request finished in 5032.421200000001ms 200 text/plain; charset=utf-8
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:57128/test/syncDb  
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:57128/test/syncDb  
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
>       Executing endpoint 'WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait)'
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
>       Executing endpoint 'WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait)'
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
>       Route matched with {action = "GetSyncDb", controller = "Test"}. Executing controller action with signature System.String GetSyncDb() on controller WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController (WebApiAsyncAwait).
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
>       Route matched with {action = "GetSyncDb", controller = "Test"}. Executing controller action with signature System.String GetSyncDb() on controller WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController (WebApiAsyncAwait).
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
>       Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
>       Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>       Executed action WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait) in 5007.105500000001ms
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>       Executed action WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait) in 5005.6482000000005ms
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
>       Executed endpoint 'WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait)'
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
>       Executed endpoint 'WebApiAsyncAwait.Controllers.TestController.GetSyncDb (WebApiAsyncAwait)'
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
>       Request finished in 5021.8341ms 200 text/plain; charset=utf-8
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
>       Request finished in 5023.8319ms 200 text/plain; charset=utf-8
> ```

Endpoint code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("syncDb")]
public string GetSyncDb()
{
    string connStr = @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AdventureWorks;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [AdventureWorks].[Sales].[CreditCard] WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'";

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var res = reader.Read();
                return "Ok";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Fiddler to send requests. Is it something with Fiddler (because logs are ok), or I'm missing something in the understanding of how this works?

Comment: What happens if you replace body of `Sync` method with just `Thread.Sleep(5000)`?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev same story, 3 req take: 5s, 5s and 10s; 4 req take: 10s, 10s, 10s, 10s

Answer (score 3):

In ASP .NET Core there is a lot of async stuff executed behind the scene. In particular,  before your controller action is executed, a thread must read and parse HTTP request sent by fiddler. After the action execution, another thread (maybe the same) is needed to write a response back to the fiddler.

So what happened in your first case with 3 requests:

1. As you allow max 2 threads, two actions were started simultaneously and were blocked immediately by sync call `reader.Read()`.
2. After ~5s, both threads completed the action `GetSyncDb()`, but the response has not yet been sent.
3. Now 2 threads are free, one can handle the 3rd request (and be blocked for ~5s) and the other can be used by ASP to write responses to the client.

Thus, 2 requests end after ~5s while the third after ~10s.

in the case of 4 requests:

1. Two actions were started simultaneously and were blocked immediately by sync call `reader.Read()`.
2. After ~5s, both threads completed the action `GetSyncDb()`, but the response has not yet been sent.
3. The other 2 requests were started and **block all available threads. ASP doesn't have any worker thread available. But it needs them to write response and complete the the first 2 requests**.
4. After next ~5s, both threads are released and ASP can finally write all responses.

Therefore all requests end after ~10s. But of course it is random. Sometimes ASP can catch the free thread and complete first responses before they are blocked by the other requests.

Comment: Thanks, this makes some sense, but still it's a bit weird. In the first palce, why it prefers to process all the requests before sending the responses (tried 30 or 31 requests with 2 threads, I have to wait at least 1:15 min until the first response).

Comment: @yekope I guess that is because of async nature of ASP. Writing a response to TCP connection includes multiple async/await calls (it sends response headers, line by line, then body, ..). As it is IO bound operation, each awaitable operation release the thread and make it available in the thread pool. So there is a big chance that your method catches the free thread and freeze it for a few seconds. Therefore such long IO bounded synchronous calls are totally not recommended.